# How to combine IF(AND) with ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Please help me with this, I'm trying to combine `ARRAYFORMULA` with `IF(AND)` function...

Did I miss something here?

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(AND(E:E>=0.625,    E:E<0.6666666667),  "4 PM",IF(AND(E1:E>=0.6666666667,  E1:E<0.75), "6 PM", IF(AND(E1:E>=0.75,E1:E<0.8333333333), "8 PM", IF(AND(E1:E>=0.8333333333, E1:E<0.9166666667), "10 PM", IF(AND(E1:E>=0.9166666667,  E1:E<=0.9999884259), "12 AM", IF(AND(E1:E>=0, E1:E<0.08333333333), "2 AM",IF(AND(E1:E>=0.08333333333, E1:E<0.1666666667), "4 AM",IF(AND(E1:E>=0.1666666667, E1:E<0.25), "6 AM", IF(AND(E1:E>=0.25,  E1:E<=0.3333333333), "8 AM", IF(AND(E1:E>=0.3333333333, E1:E<0.4166666667), "10 AM", IF(AND(E1:E>=0.4166666667, E1:E<0.5), "12 PM", IF(AND(E1:E>=0.5,  E1:E<=0.9999884259), "2 PM", IF(AND(E1:E>=0.9999884259, E1:E<0.65), "3 PM","NA"))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Couldn't you have used something like this in your original (non-array) formula =ROUNDUP(e1*12,0)/12 ? Then the array formula would be a lot easier.

Comment: BTW the last condition AND(E1:E>=0.9999884259, E1:E<0.65) can never be true :-)

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
IF((E1:E>=0.625)        *(E1:E<0.6666666667),  "4 PM",
IF((E1:E>=0.6666666667) *(E1:E<0.75),          "6 PM", 
IF((E1:E>=0.75)         *(E1:E<0.8333333333),  "8 PM", 
IF((E1:E>=0.8333333333) *(E1:E<0.9166666667),  "10 PM", 
IF((E1:E>=0.9166666667) *(E1:E<=0.9999884259), "12 AM", 
IF((E1:E>=0)            *(E1:E<0.08333333333), "2 AM",
IF((E1:E>=0.08333333333)*(E1:E<0.1666666667),  "4 AM",
IF((E1:E>=0.1666666667) *(E1:E<0.25),          "6 AM", 
IF((E1:E>=0.25)         *(E1:E<=0.3333333333), "8 AM", 
IF((E1:E>=0.3333333333) *(E1:E<0.4166666667),  "10 AM", 
IF((E1:E>=0.4166666667) *(E1:E<0.5),           "12 PM", 
IF((E1:E>=0.5)          *(E1:E<=0.9999884259), "2 PM", 
IF((E1:E>=0.9999884259) *(E1:E<0.65),          "3 PM", "NA"))))))))))))))
```

**alternatives: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would do the same job

```
=arrayformula(ROUNDUP(E:E*12,0)/12)
```

if formatted as time or

```
=arrayformula(text(ROUNDUP(E:E*12,0)/12,"h:mm am/pm"))
```

to include the format.